# Get value from defaultMuleMessage

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mel

I am trying to extract a value from the defaultMuleMessage datatype but cannot get the syntax correct in Mule 3.7.3.  Can anyone help?

The value I am trying to get to is found in the variable tab in the Mule debugger:

```
initialMessage (org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage)
-> properties (org.mule.MessagePropertiesContext)
--> inboundMap (org.mule.util.CopyOnWrite.CaseInsensitiveMap)
---> 7 (java.util.Collections$UnmodifiavleMap$UnmodifiableEntrySet$UnmodifiableEntry)
```

At 7 is the key=organization

If I type "initialMessage" into the debugger I receive this:

```
org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage
{
  id=6980b240-b882-11e6-85f7-d26120524153
  payload=java.lang.String
  correlationId=<not set>
  correlationGroup=-1
  correlationSeq=-1
  encoding=UTF-8
  exceptionPayload=<not set>

Message properties:
  INVOCATION scoped properties:
    _ApikitResponseTransformer_apikitRouterRequest=yes
    _ApikitResponseTransformer_bestMatchRepresentation=application/json
    _ApikitResponseTransformer_contractMimeTypes=[MimeType{type='application/json'}]
    counter=1
    deterministicOrchestration=true
    initialMessage=<<<MuleMessage>>>
    logLevel=INFO
    maskingEnabled=true
    messageFormat=JSON
    messageLocation=CLIENT_REQUEST
    mongoOperation=insert-object-from-map
    mongoQuery={messageLocation=client_request, payload={NullPayload}}
    mongoSynchronous=false
    nextOrchestratedFlow=products-getProducts
    orchestrationFlows=[products-getProducts]
    prevResponse=''
  INBOUND scoped properties:
    accept=*/*
    accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, peerdist
    accept-language=en-GB
    organization=abc
    connection=Keep-Alive
    host=localhost:8089
    http.listener.path=/api/*
    http.method=GET
    http.query.params=ParameterMap{[]}
    http.query.string=
    http.remote.address=/127.0.0.1
    http.request.path=/api/products
    http.request.uri=/api/products
    http.scheme=http
    http.uri.params=ParameterMap{[]}
    http.version=HTTP/1.1
    referer=http://localhost:8089/api/console/
    ua-cpu=AMD64
    user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; managedpc; rv:11.0) like Gecko
    x-p2p-peerdist=Version=1.0
    x-requested-with=XMLHttpRequest
  OUTBOUND scoped properties:
    Content-Type=text/plain;charset=UTF-8
    MULE_ENCODING=UTF-8
  SESSION scoped properties:
    country=usa
    resource=products
}
```

I'm trying to retrieve the "organization=abc" value.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the **initialMessage** variable is in the INVOCATION Scope, try the following:

```
#[message.getInvocationProperty('initialMessage').getInboundProperty('organization')]
```

UPDATE:

`#[message]` is of type [MessageContext](https://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.3.0/apidocs/org/mule/el/context/MessageContext.html), so you cannot get Invocation properties directly (only from MuleMessage). The expression above will not work.

UPDATE2:

Try the following `#[flowVars.initialMessage.getInboundProperty('organization')]`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get inbound property (e.g. called `organization`) from mule message using MEL, you just have to:

```
#[message.inboundProperties.'organization']
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The mule flow I am looking at does not have any inbound properties at the point I need to reference organization and looks like they have stored them away in a variable called initialMessage so need to find out how I would write the MEL expression to retrieve the value in the structure above.  I have tried get and traversing through the initialMessage variable but with little success

Answer (score 0):

From what I could get from the question and the comments for the previous answer.

You are looking to get a inbound property from a MuleMessage which itself is available as a property in the message of your flow.

Try the following solution.

```
#[message.inboundProperties.'initialMessage'.getInboundProperty('organization')]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try getting like this, #[message.inboundProperties.organization]